# Export php form data to Excel or PDF

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have function called "resultAction" where I store all the information in $data to print in div table.

Now I want to export the same form data to excel.
I want to pass the same form data to another function called "reportAction", where i failing to do that, i am returing the $data which fails.

```
function resultAction()
{   
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
       $data[$i]['device_type']     = $result[$i]['device_type'];
       $data[$i]['region_name']     = $result[$i]['region_name'];
   }

   echo  Zend_Json::encode($data);
   sleep(2);
   $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
   $this->_helper ->layout()->disableLayout();
   return $data;
}

function reportAction()   {
    $res = $this ->resultAction   // here it fails
}
```

Comment: All this code is full of syntax errors. Are these functions members of some class?

Comment: hey i have just put the code.. please ignore syntax errors

Comment: My guess is that it's Zend_Frameword @Mchl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the forward function

```
function reportAction()   {
    $this->_forward('result');   // here it's not supposed to fail
}
```

Comment: but how reportAction () will know it should call resultAction which returns $data.. just got confused

Comment: $this->_forward('result'); calls result Action i guess you're using Zend Framework ?